# Writing Python Selenium output to Excel

Tags: python, excel, selenium

I have written a script to scrape product information from online websites. The goal is to write these information out to an Excel file. Due to my limited Python knowledge, I only know how to export using Out-file in Powershell. But the result is that information for each product is printed on separate lines. I would prefer there to be one line per product.

My desired output can be seen in the picture. I would prefer to my output to look like the second version, but I can live with the first one.

[image]

---

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException    

url = "http://www.strem.com/"
cas = ['16940-92-4','29796-57-4','13569-57-8','15635-87-7']

for i in cas:
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get(url)

    driver.find_element_by_id("selectbox_input").click()
    driver.find_element_by_id("selectbox_input_cas").click()

    inputElement = driver.find_element_by_name("keyword")
    inputElement.send_keys(i)
    inputElement.submit()

    # Check if a particular element exists; returns True/False          
    def check_exists_by_xpath(xpath):
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            return False
        return True

    xpath1 = ".//div[@class = 'error']" # element containing error message
    xpath2 = ".//table[@class = 'product_list tiles']" # element containing table to select product from
    #xpath3 = ".//div[@class = 'catalog_number']" # when selection is needed, returns the first catalog number

    if check_exists_by_xpath(xpath1):
        print "cas# %s is not found on Strem." %i
        driver.quit() 
    else:
        if check_exists_by_xpath(xpath2):
            catNum = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class = 'catalog_number']")
            catNum.click()

            country = driver.find_element_by_name("country")
            for option in country.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
                if option.text == "USA":
                    option.click()
            country.submit()

            name = driver.find_element_by_id("header_description").text
            prodNum = driver.find_element_by_class_name("catalog_number").text
            print(i)
            print(name.encode("utf-8"))
            print(prodNum)

            skus_by_xpath = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                lambda driver : driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//td[@class='size']")
            )

            for output in skus_by_xpath:
                print(output.text)

            prices_by_xpath = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                lambda driver : driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//td[@class='price']")
            )

            for result in prices_by_xpath:
                print(result.text[3:]) #To remove last three characters, use :-3

            driver.quit()
        else:
            country = driver.find_element_by_name("country")
            for option in country.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
                if option.text == "USA":
                    option.click()
            country.submit()

            name = driver.find_element_by_id("header_description").text
            prodNum = driver.find_element_by_class_name("catalog_number").text
            print(i)
            print(name.encode("utf-8"))
            print(prodNum)

            skus_by_xpath = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                lambda driver : driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//td[@class='size']")
            )

            for output in skus_by_xpath:
                print(output.text)

            prices_by_xpath = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                lambda driver : driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//td[@class='price']")
            )

            for result in prices_by_xpath:
                print(result.text[3:]) #To remove last three characters, use :-3

            driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

https://pythonhosted.org/openpyxl/tutorial.html

This is a tutorial for a python library that allows manipulation for python
There are other libraries but I like using this one.

from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()

then use the methods given to write your data 
and then

wb.save(filename)

really easy to get started.

This is a pdf tutorial for using xlwt and xlrd, but I don't really use these modules alot. 
http://www.simplistix.co.uk/presentations/python-excel.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I usually find that writing to CSV is the safest way to get data into excel. I use something like the following code:

```
import csv
import sys
import time
import datetime
from os import fsync

ts=time.time() #get the time, to use in a filename
ds=datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M') #format the time for the filename
f2=open('OutputLog_'+ds+'.txt','w') #my file is output_log + the date time stamp
f2.write(str('Column1DataPoint'+','+'Column2DataPoint') #write your text, separate your data with comma's
#if you're running a long loop, and want to keep your file up to date with the proces do these two steps in your loop too
f2.flush() 
fsync(f2.fileno())

#once the loop is finished and data is writtin, close your file
f2.close()
```

I think for you, the change to the above code would be to change the write line something like the following:

```
f2.write(str(i+','+name.encode("utf-8")+','+prodNum+','+output.text)
```