# type error: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'WebElement' and 'WebElement' for selenium

Tags: python, selenium

im trying to export an excel spreadsheet and its giving me problems, what im trying to do, is store the information in the [spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437727/python-write-to-excel-spreadsheet). Any Suggestions ?
i have referenced a number of resources on here, like this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24899749/writing-python-selenium-output-to-excel)

**Main.py**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import csv
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import unittest





class Test():
    # filename = "list.csv"
    # f = open(filename,"w")
    # headers = "listing name, aval \n"

    # f.write(headers)

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.get("https://orlando.craigslist.org/search/apa?s=100")
        self.filename = "list.csv"
        self.f = open(self.filename,"w")
        self.headers = "listing name, aval \n"

    def task(self):
        driver = self.driver
        filename = self.filename
        f = self.f
        headers = self.headers
        ln = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="sortable-results"]/ul/li/p/a')
        size = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="sortable-results"]/ul/li/p/a'))
        for i in range(0, size):
            ln = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="sortable-results"]/ul/li/p/a')
            ln = ln[i]
            self.getLn(ln)
            ln.click()
            av = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/section/section/section/div[1]/p[1]/span[3]')
            self.getAv(av)
            back = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/section/header/nav/ul/li[3]/p/a').click()
            WebDriverWait(driver,3)
            f.write(ln + av + "\n")
            if i == 5:
                f.close()
                break





    def getLn(self,ln):
        driver = self.driver
        ln = ln
        if ln:
            print (ln.text)
        else:
            print ("No listing name")



    def getAv(self,av):
        driver = self.driver
        if av:
            print (av.text)
        else:
            print ("No listing name")


    def initialize():
        return Test

    def teardown(self):
        self.driver.quit()



run = Test()
run.setUp()
tas = run.task()
run.teardown()






if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Traceback error:

```
  File "main.py", line 41, in task
    f.write(ln + av + "\n")
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'WebElement' and 'WebElement'
```

**EDIT, error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 77, in <module>
    tas = run.task()
  File "main.py", line 41, in task
    f.write(ln.text + av.text + "\n")
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 73, in text
    return self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_TEXT)['value']
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 491, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 238, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 193, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=56.0.2924.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.2 x86_64)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error because `ln` and `av` are WebElements, and you are not able to add them.

```
def task(self):
        driver = self.driver
        filename = self.filename
        f = self.f
        headers = self.headers
        ln = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="sortable-results"]/ul/li/p/a')
        size = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="sortable-results"]/ul/li/p/a'))
        for i in range(0, size):
            ln = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="sortable-results"]/ul/li/p/a')
            ln = ln[i]
            self.getLn(ln)
            ln.click()
            av = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/section/section/section/div[1]/p[1]/span[3]')
            self.getAv(av)
            back = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/section/header/nav/ul/li[3]/p/a').click()
            WebDriverWait(driver,3)
            f.write(ln + av + "\n") ### Adding WebElement's isn't allowed
                f.close()
                break
```

Maybe your intent is to concatenate (join) the text from the elements on the page. In that case, Change `f.write(ln + av + "\n")` to `f.write(ln.text + av.text + "\n")`.

I hope this answers your question. Happy coding!

Comment: thanks for putting that together, however i get the error in the edit

Comment: @Owl Man, instead of using `.text`, try using `.get_attribute("text")` or `.get_attribute("textContent")`.

Comment: i figured it out, it was where what line i placed it ** f.write(ln.text + av.text + "\n")**

Comment: @OwlMan, I'm glad your problem got solved. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

av and ln are WebElement, so you can't concatenate them.
I supose you want the text from the WebElement so you need to access it like this:

```
f.write(ln.text + av.text + "\n")
```

Comment: that is true, but it now shows the error in the edit above

Comment: this is a new Error and a new question, you should lookup the error message. selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document  ==> maybe this will help you understand the error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27003423/python-selenium-stale-element-fix