# Iterating over click for the table cells containing the link and finding it by link text while scraping data using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium

I want to save all the scrape data from on click on Survey Number displaying the textarea containing the numbers in the CSV file ..From my code only the last pages having the survey numbers are saved in CSV file .Other data of page1 and page2 not able to save

enter code here

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_link_text('SurveyNo')
page_num = 2
while True:
      link1 = driver.find_element_by_link_text(str(page_num))
      link1.click()
      soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
      table = soup.find("table" , attrs = 
      {'id':'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder5_grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate' })
      data = []
      for l in range(len(links)):

           newlinks = driver.find_elements_by_link_text('SurveyNo')
           newlinks[l].click()
           soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
           td1 = soup.find("textarea", attrs={'class': 'textbox'})
           data.append(td1.text)
           for data1 in data:
                with open(os.path.expanduser("output.csv"),"w") as result:
                wr = csv.writer(result, dialect='excel')
                wr.writerow(data)
      page_num += 1
```

Output:
Please see the image[Outfile image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5rNJ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done a bit modification.instead of table I have taken the links count and then iterate the links.Let me know if this work for you.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
URL = 'http://www.igrmaharashtra.gov.in/eASR/eASRCommon.aspx?hDistName=Pune'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(URL)
Select(driver.find_element_by_name('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder5$ddlTaluka')).select_by_value('5')
Select(driver.find_element_by_name('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder5$ddlVillage')).select_by_value('1853')

links = driver.find_elements_by_link_text('SurveyNo')

for l in range(len(links)):
    newlinks = driver.find_elements_by_link_text('SurveyNo')
    newlinks[l].click()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    td1 = soup.find("textarea", attrs={'class': 'textbox'})
    print(td1.text)
```

OutPut:

```
1239 , 1520 , 1524 , 1231 , 1223 , 1339 , 1517 , 1518 , 1521 , 1523 , 1528 , 1540 , 1244 , 1519 , 1522 , 1243 , 1186 , 1187 , 1224 , 1227 , 1234 , 1235 , 1238 , 1241 , 1228 
1646 , 1504 , 1527 , 1532 , 1536 , 1541 , 2471 , 1641 , 2463 , 1691 , 1751 , 1755 , 1770 , 1915 , 1929 , 1634 , 1750 , 1771 , 1769 , 1767 , 1766 , 1754 , 1694 , 1752 , 1913 , 2468 , 1753 , 1914 , 1916 , 1919 , 1928 , 1693 , 2467 , 2028 , 2472 , 2473 , 2474 , 2462 , 1539 , 2464 , 1529 , 1530 , 1531 , 1533 , 1506 , 1534 , 1505 , 1535 , 1649 , 1538 , 1507 , 1547 , 1603 , 1604 , 1635 , 1636 , 1640 , 1642 , 1645 , 1647 , 1648 , 1537 
1620 , 1621 
1501 , 1482 , 1548 , 1544 , 1513 , 1497 , 1681 , 1677 , 1673 , 1552 , 1486 , 1525 , 1478 , 1474 , 1470 , 1466 , 1463 , 1459 , 1493 , 1490 , 1579 , 1669 , 1665 , 1662 , 1658 , 1608 , 1602 , 1599 , 1595 , 1591 , 1509 , 1583 , 1556 , 1575 , 1572 , 1568 , 1564 , 1560 , 1587 , 1574 , 1592 , 1593 , 1594 , 1596 , 1597 , 1598 , 1615 , 1600 , 1601 , 1590 , 1605 , 1606 , 1607 , 1609 , 1610 , 1611 , 1612 , 1613 , 1614 , 1576 , 1667 , 1616 , 1565 , 1566 , 1567 , 1569 , 1570 , 1577 , 1573 , 1589 , 1578 , 1580 , 1581 , 1582 , 1584 , 1585 , 1586 , 1588 , 1571 , 1671 , 1656 , 1657 , 1659 , 1660 , 1661 , 1663 , 1666 , 1664 , 1670 , 1653 , 1672 , 1674 , 1675 , 1676 , 1678 , 1679 , 1680 , 1563 , 1668 , 1633 , 1618 , 1619 , 1622 , 1623 , 1624 , 1625 , 1629 , 1630 , 1655 , 1632 , 1654 , 1638 , 1643 , 1644 , 1457 , 1650 , 1651 , 1652 , 1617 , 1631 , 1467 , 1479 , 1455 , 1456 , 1340 , 1458 , 1461 , 1462 , 1453 , 1465 , 1452 , 1468 , 1469 , 1471 , 1472 , 1473 , 1475 , 1476 , 1477 , 1464 , 1352 , 1562 , 1460 , 1341 , 1344 , 1345 , 1346 , 1348 , 1454 , 1351 , 1349 , 1353 , 1445 , 1446 , 1447 , 1448 , 1449 , 1450 , 1451 , 1350 , 1550 , 1514 , 1515 , 1516 , 1526 , 1542 , 1543 , 1545 , 1512 , 1549 , 1554 , 1551 , 1553 , 1555 , 1558 , 1559 , 1561 , 1480 , 1347 , 1546 , 1488 , 1481 , 1483 , 1557 , 1511 , 1484 , 1485 , 1487 , 1489 , 1491 , 1492 , 1498 , 1503 , 1494 , 1500 , 1502 , 1499 , 1508 , 1496 , 1510 , 1495 
1121 , 1125 , 1129 , 1133 , 1110 , 1083 , 1118 , 1114 , 1106 , 1102 , 1098 , 1094 , 1137 , 1087 , 1225 , 1091 , 1232 , 1289 , 1286 , 1282 , 1278 , 1274 , 1270 , 1266 , 1262 , 1259 , 1255 , 1251 , 1216 , 1240 , 1141 , 1071 , 1220 , 1212 , 1208 , 1204 , 1200 , 1196 , 1193 , 1189 , 1152 , 1148 , 1145 , 1247 , 1745 , 1718 , 1706 , 1710 , 1722 , 1725 , 1729 , 1733 , 1698 , 1741 , 1695 , 1749 , 1758 , 1762 , 1768 , 1714 , 1075 , 1079 , 1737 , 1301 , 1064 , 1702 , 1688 , 1067 , 1060 , 1297 , 1305 , 1309 , 1313 , 1316 , 1320 , 1293 , 1311 , 1302 , 1312 , 1308 , 1307 , 1310 , 1306 , 1299 , 1303 , 1300 , 1315 , 1328 , 1298 , 1296 , 1295 , 1304 , 1327 , 1334 , 1333 , 1264 , 1294 , 1332 , 1331 , 1326 , 1329 , 1318 , 1325 , 1324 , 1323 , 1322 , 1321 , 1319 , 1330 , 1254 , 1267 , 1265 , 1263 , 1261 , 1260 , 1258 , 1269 , 1256 , 1271 , 1253 , 1252 , 1250 , 1249 , 1335 , 1726 , 1257 , 1280 , 1291 , 1290 , 1288 , 1287 , 1285 , 1284 , 1268 , 1281 , 1292 , 1279 , 1277 , 1276 , 1275 , 1273 , 1272 , 1283 , 1314 , 1716 , 1735 , 1734 , 1732 , 1731 , 1730 , 1738 , 1727 , 1739 , 1724 , 1248 , 1721 , 1720 , 1719 , 1723 , 1728 , 1748 , 1765 , 1764 , 1763 , 1761 , 1760 , 1759 , 1736 , 1756 , 1715 , 1747 , 1746 , 1744 , 1743 , 1742 , 1740 , 1757 , 1628 , 1717 , 1686 , 1685 , 1684 , 1683 , 1682 , 1689 , 1637 , 1690 , 1627 , 1626 , 1343 , 1342 , 1338 , 1337 , 1639 , 1703 , 1713 , 1712 , 1711 , 1709 , 1708 , 1707 , 1687 , 1704 , 1336 , 1701 , 1700 , 1699 , 1697 , 1696 , 1692 , 1705 , 1112 , 1147 , 1122 , 1120 , 1119 , 1117 , 1116 , 1124 , 1113 , 1126 , 1111 , 1109 , 1108 , 1107 , 1105 , 1104 , 1115 , 1135 , 1146 , 1144 , 1143 , 1142 , 1140 , 1139 , 1123 , 1136 , 1100 , 1134 , 1132 , 1131 , 1130 , 1128 , 1127 , 1138 , 1062 , 1073 , 1072 , 1070 , 1069 , 1068 , 1066 , 1103 , 1063 , 1077 , 1061 , 1059 , 1057 , 1058 , 1246 , 1317 , 1065 , 1086 , 1090 , 1099 , 1097 , 1096 , 1095 , 1093 , 1074 , 1089 , 1076 , 1085 , 1084 , 1082 , 1081 , 1080 , 1078 , 1101 , 1092 , 1198 , 1209 , 1207 , 1206 , 1205 , 1203 , 1202 , 1188 , 1199 , 1213 , 1197 , 1195 , 1194 , 1192 , 1191 , 1190 , 1201 , 1229 , 1245 , 1242 , 1237 , 1236 , 1088 , 1149 , 1210 , 1230 , 1211 , 1226 , 1222 , 1221 , 1219 , 1218 , 1215 , 1214 , 1233 , 1185 , 1166 , 1165 , 1164 , 1163 , 1162 , 1160 , 1167 , 1157 , 1161 , 1217 , 1156 , 1155 , 1154 , 1153 , 1151 , 1150 , 1158 , 1179 , 1177 , 1175 , 1159 , 1178 , 1176 , 1174 , 1173 , 1169 , 1168 , 1171 , 1181 , 1170 , 1180 , 1172
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution

Comment: Thanks for the solution Kajal , but  it also need to be save in the proper excel file .
As I am a beginner , so need your kind solution

Comment: I have done some changes while saving the file . and also want the survey numbers from other pages  and need to save the data .

Comment: kindly need the solution

Answer (score 0):

I think your mistake is possibly that `link` returns as a list and then you only tell it to click once.  You may need another loop along the lines of

```
for x in link;
    x.click();
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
....
```

(and you may want to rename your variable as `links` so you can say `for link in links`)

Comment: No ..The code is working properly .I just need to save the scrape data td1.text into the excel file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24899749/writing-python-selenium-output-to-excel

Please see that answer which offers several ways to write selenium output into an excel file.

Comment: Notice the accepted answer says "I have done a bit modification.instead of table I have taken the links count and then iterate the links.Let me know if this work for you."  This is what my answer does, and it is necessary since calling `links.click()` does not work and you have to iterate through them with a simple for loop as above.